# Authenticating with Azure Active Directory: RoleProvider for ClaimsIdentity?

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, roles, claims-based-identity

Fellow developers, I'm updating an IIS web application from using Windows Authentication to using Azure Active Directory instead. The setup looks fine: I can successfully authenticate, and I get the user's identity as a ClaimsIdentity.

However, this does not mesh well with my current use of `System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider`. When doing an `IsInRole()` check, the role provider detects that the current identity is not a `WindowsIdentity` and throws a `ProviderException`:

> Method is only supported if the user name parameter matches the user name in the current Windows Identity.

I believe I need to configure the application's role manager to use a `ClaimsIdentity`-friendly provider. Is there a standard role provider class that plays well with the `ClaimsIdentity`, or will I need to build a custom role provider?

Edit: I've built my own custom role manager that appears to only need an implementation of `GetRolesForUser(string username)` method. It solves my problem, but doesn't answer my question :)

Comment: To avoid the `ProviderException` while doing `IsInRole()` we need to add the below tag in `Web.config` file under the `<system.web>`.
`<roleManager enabled="true" />`

Comment: @Harshitha That setting was already in my web.config, but the `WindowsTokenRoleProvider` only accepts `WindowsIdentity` (the `IsInRole()` implementation has a type-check built-in), so it does not work with the `ClaimsIdentity`.

Answer (score 0):

*The base class of Claims Identity is the* `System.Security.Claims namespace.` *Hence it needs to be used in the project*.
`using System.Security.Claims;`

*To achieve this, we need to use customize the ClaimsIdentity based on our requirement as shown below.*
[image]

*Below is the code snippet:*

```
string Identity_Provider_ClaimType = @"Some_claims/identityprovider";
string Default_IdentityProvider_ClaimValue = "Some_ClaimsIdentity";

var id = new ClaimsIdentity(
    DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType,
    ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType
);

id.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, users.UserId.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String));
id.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, users.UserName, ClaimValueTypes.String));
id.AddClaim(new Claim(Identity_Provider_ClaimType, Default_IdentityProvider_ClaimValue, ClaimValueTypes.String));
id.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, users.UserName, ClaimValueTypes.String));
```